# AC_SEARCH_LIBS does not find function in gswteos-10

Tags: autotools, autoconf

I've [revised gswteos-10 to include an autotools build](https://github.com/bluesquall/GSW-C/tree/autotools) to ease using it in a project where many of the other packages also use autotools. The project is cross-compiled for arm, but my problem also occurs on my amd64 laptop, as well as in [bitbucket CI/CD pipelines](https://bitbucket.org/bluesquall/test-gswteos-10/addon/pipelines/). I've reduced the problem to a fairly simple example [here](https://bitbucket.org/bluesquall/test-gswteos-10/).

Using:

```
AC_SEARCH_LIBS([gsw_z_from_p], [gswteos-10])
```

I expect `./configure` to give:

```
checking for library containing gsw_z_from_p... -lgswteos-10
```

but instead I see:

```
checking for library containing gsw_z_from_p... no
```

In the meantime, I can get the project to compile by manually adding

```
z_from_p_LDADD = -lgswteos-10 -lm
```

to `Makefile.am`, but I'd like to fix it the *right* way.

It may be something simple I'm missing in the documentation. I suspect it has to do with the way I added the autotools build to the library.

- After installing `gswteos-10`, I did run `ldconfig`.
- I've also tried installing `gswteos-10` to `/usr` instead of `/usr/local`, and that didn't fix it. (It was a shot in the dark, since I have `/usr/local/lib` listed in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/local.conf`.)
- I've confirmed that the function `gsw_z_from_p` exists by compiling with the manual `LDADD`, and:

```
nm /usr/local/lib/libgswteos-10.so | grep gsw_z_from_p
0000000000022b40 T gsw_z_from_p
```

I'm taking a stab at setting it up with `pkg-config`, but it seems like this should be something `autoconf` can do on its own...

---

Here is [the diff for the commit in my autotools branch of the library](https://github.com/bluesquall/GSW-C/commit/3ee433b479b1b728f9bee2d728be10b0dcda9a15) that fixed the autoconf issue for my simplified example (and my real application):

```
diff --git a/Makefile.am b/Makefile.am
index eeafcf2..db8eda8 100644
--- a/Makefile.am
+++ b/Makefile.am
@@ -11,7 +11,7 @@ pkgconfig_DATA = gswteos-10.pc
 libgswteos_10_la_SOURCES = gsw_oceanographic_toolbox.c gsw_saar.c \
                           gsw_internal_const.h
 libgswteos_10_la_CFLAGS = $(AM_CFLAGS)
-libgswteos_10_la_LDFLAGS = -module -shared -export-dynamic \
+libgswteos_10_la_LDFLAGS = -lm -module -shared -export-dynamic \
                           -version-info 3:5:0

 TESTS = gsw_check_functions
```

Here is the pertinent part of `config.log` for the test application before:

```
configure:3455: checking for library containing gsw_z_from_p
configure:3486: gcc -o conftest -g -O2   conftest.c  >&5
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccGeQnML.o: in function `main':
/home/squall/src/foss/test-gswteos-10/conftest.c:22: undefined reference to `gsw_z_from_p'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:3486: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "test-gswteos-10"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "test-gswteos-10"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "dc168980"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "test-gswteos-10 dc168980"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "https://bitbucket.org/bluesquall/test-gsw-teos-10/issues"
| #define PACKAGE_URL "https://bitbucket.org/bluesquall/test-gsw-teos-10"
| #define PACKAGE "test-gswteos-10"
| #define VERSION "dc168980"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| /* Override any GCC internal prototype to avoid an error.
|    Use char because int might match the return type of a GCC
|    builtin and then its argument prototype would still apply.  */
| #ifdef __cplusplus
| extern "C"
| #endif
| char gsw_z_from_p ();
| int
| main ()
| {
| return gsw_z_from_p ();
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3486: gcc -o conftest -g -O2   conftest.c -lgswteos-10   >&5
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libgswteos-10.so: undefined reference to `atan2'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libgswteos-10.so: undefined reference to `sin'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libgswteos-10.so: undefined reference to `exp'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libgswteos-10.so: undefined reference to `pow'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libgswteos-10.so: undefined reference to `sqrt'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libgswteos-10.so: undefined reference to `clog'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:3486: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "test-gswteos-10"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "test-gswteos-10"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "dc168980"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "test-gswteos-10 dc168980"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "https://bitbucket.org/bluesquall/test-gsw-teos-10/issues"
| #define PACKAGE_URL "https://bitbucket.org/bluesquall/test-gsw-teos-10"
| #define PACKAGE "test-gswteos-10"
| #define VERSION "dc168980"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| /* Override any GCC internal prototype to avoid an error.
|    Use char because int might match the return type of a GCC
|    builtin and then its argument prototype would still apply.  */
| #ifdef __cplusplus
| extern "C"
| #endif
| char gsw_z_from_p ();
| int
| main ()
| {
| return gsw_z_from_p ();
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3503: result: no
```

and after:

```
configure:3455: checking for library containing gsw_z_from_p
configure:3486: gcc -o conftest -g -O2   conftest.c  >&5
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc5lIEqu.o: in function `main':
/home/squall/src/foss/test-gswteos-10/conftest.c:22: undefined reference to `gsw_z_from_p'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:3486: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "test-gswteos-10"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "test-gswteos-10"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "dc168980"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "test-gswteos-10 dc168980"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "https://bitbucket.org/bluesquall/test-gsw-teos-10/issues"
| #define PACKAGE_URL "https://bitbucket.org/bluesquall/test-gsw-teos-10"
| #define PACKAGE "test-gswteos-10"
| #define VERSION "dc168980"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| /* Override any GCC internal prototype to avoid an error.
|    Use char because int might match the return type of a GCC
|    builtin and then its argument prototype would still apply.  */
| #ifdef __cplusplus
| extern "C"
| #endif
| char gsw_z_from_p ();
| int
| main ()
| {
| return gsw_z_from_p ();
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3486: gcc -o conftest -g -O2   conftest.c -lgswteos-10   >&5
configure:3486: $? = 0
configure:3503: result: -lgswteos-10
```

After @JohnBollinger clued me in on looking in `config.log`, the root cause was obvious -- the programs couldn't find references to functions like `atan2`.

Adding `-lm` to `libgswteos_10_la_LDFLAGS` fixes it so that any program using `libgswteos-10` will be able to find those symbols.

Another solution (perhaps more strictly correct) would be to use the optional fifth argument:

```
AC_SEARCH_LIBS([gsw_z_from_p], [gswteos-10], [], [], [m])
```

Comment: What does `configure`'s log have to say about it?  It should tell you what source program and link commands were used for the test, and what error occurred.

Comment: As a first guess, though, the problem could be a link failure on account of some unsatisfied dependency of `-lgswteos-10`, maybe `-lm`.

Comment: That was exactly it, thank you.

In `Makefile.am` for `libgswteos`, I put `-lm` in the `LDADD` for the test program, but missed it in `libgswteos_10_la_LDFLAGS`.

Comment: I was not talking about a build-time link issue but rather a `configure`-time link issue.  The contents of your `Makefile.am` are irrelevant to `configure`'s tests, which is what this question asks about.  There are conventional ways to approach such a problem with the Autotools, but before I write an answer describing them I want to be confident that it will address the issue you're actually having.  This is why I asked about `configure`'s log, which, in case you were unaware, it writes in a file named `configure.log`.

Comment: I think I may not have been clear about where I added `-lm` to fix it; it was in `Makefile.am` for the library, not for the test program.

I'll follow up with the `configure.log` before & after the change when I get a chance to change it back and generate both. Hopefully that will make everything clearer.